# Comparing documents - document similarity

Tags: java, nlp, similarity, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I am currently conducting a java project in NLP/IR, and are fairly new to this. 
The project consists of a collection with around 1000 documents, where each document has about 100 words, structured as bag of words with term-frequency. I want to find similar documents based on a document(from the collection).

Using TF-IDF, calculating tf-idf for the query(a given document) and every other document in the collection, then comparing these values as a vector with cosine similarity. Could this give some insight in their similarity? Or would it not be reasonable, because of the big query(document)?
Is there any other similarity measures that could work better?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

TF-IDF-based similarity, typically using a cosine to compare a vector representing the query terms to a set of vector representing the TF-IDF values of the documents, is a common approach to calculate "similarity".

Mind that there "similarity" is a very generic term. In the IR domain, you typically speak rather of "relevance". Texts can be similar on many levels: in the same language, using the same characters, using the same words, talking about the same people, using a similarly complex grammatical structure and much more - consequently, there are many many measures. Search the web for text similarity to find many publications but also open-source frameworks and libraries that implement different measures.

Today, "semantic similarity" is attracting more interest than the traditional keyword-based IR models. If this is your area of interest, you might look into the results of the [SemEval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SemEval) shared tasks years 2012-2015.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand the different "types" of similarity you mentioned. If I would go with the TF-IDF, cosine similarity approach. Would i just use one of the documents as a query for the rest of the collection(except the same one)? Or is it any other ways?

Comment: Queries are typically short, while documents are typically longer. When comparing documents, you probably want to compare their TF-IDF vectors to each other. However, when you feed a full document as a query to an IR system, it may just treat it as a bag of words (TF = 1, IDF = 1 for all words in the bag) - so you probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to compare two documents using TF-IDF, you can do that. Since you mention that each doc contains 100 words, in the worst case there might be 1000*100 unique words. So, im assuming your vectors are built on all unique words (since all documents should be represented in same dimension). If the no. of unique words are too high, you could try using some dimensionality reduction techniques to reduce the dimensions (like PCA). But what you are trying to do is right, you can always compare documents like this for finding similarity between documents.

If you want similarity more in the sense of semantics you should look at using LDA (topic modelling) type techniques.